# Sum values in datatable column til 0 is found (subtotal)

Tags: datatable, subtotal

I have a datatable with the following values:

Name1   |   1

Name1   |   1

Name1   |   1

Name1   |   0

Name1   |   1

Name1   |   0

Name2   |   1

Name2   |   0

and I want to end up with the following values in another datatable, basically subtotaling the column until a zero is found

Name1   |   3

Name1   |   1

Name2   |   1

I can put the original data into an array, a list, it doesn't matter, I just can't figure out how to do this!

I haven't tried anything that came close, so I don't have any code to add.

Thank you!

Comment: can you share your piece of code that you tried?

Comment: Truthfully I couldn't figure out any logic to use, I am baffled, so I didn't include any.  All I could come up with is something like int sum = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Compute("SUM(CountOfDays)", string.Empty));, and there was no way to introduce any logic to subtotal when a 0 is encountered.

Comment: Are you talking about jquery http://datatables.net

Answer (score 0):

I created a couple of loops that manipulated the data using two columns in the datagridview.  This isn't an actual answer, it's more of a hack, but I don't plan on checking this post any more and didn't want to leave it hanging